# Opengl transparent background and Camera Preview don't like texturing

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, overlay, textures

I have been working on creating an opengl camera overlay and succesfully placed a 3d cube with a transparent backround over a camera preview however the problem occurs when adding a texture.

The texture its self appears for a few seconds then the whole opengl cube disappears leaving just the camera preview running.

This is where i add the camera and opengl views

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        glView = new GLLayer(this);

        mPreview = new CamLayer(this);

        camera = new CameraSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(glView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        addContentView(camera, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); // does not work when texture added

}
```

This is the class giving me all the trouble i use the method bindCameraTexture to dynamicly re-texture the cube with a bitmap this works with out a transparent back-round.

```
public GLLayer(Context c) {
    super(c);

    this.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    this.setRenderer(this);
    this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);//sets the backround to transparent
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    onDrawFrameCounter++;

    drawFrame(mBitmap);
    mSecs += 1;
    drawFrameAt(mBitmap, mSecs);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    bindCameraTexture(gl,mBitmap);

    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 4.2f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------Does not need to Rotate

    gl.glRotatef(onDrawFrameCounter,1,0,0); //Rotate the camera image
    gl.glRotatef((float)Math.sin(onDrawFrameCounter/20.0f)*40,0,1,0); //Rotate the camera image
    gl.glRotatef((float)Math.cos(onDrawFrameCounter/40.0f)*40,0,0,1); //Rotate the camera image

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------

    gl.glNormal3f(0,0,1);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);          
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,12, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,16, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,20, 4);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 4.2f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);        
}

public void videoUpdate(int seconds)
{
    drawFrame(mBitmap);
    mSecs += seconds;
    drawFrameAt(mBitmap, mSecs);    
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(240, 240, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //----I FOR GOT THIS I AM STUPID
    openFile();

    videoUpdate(1);

    bindCameraTexture(gl,mBitmap);
    //createTexture(gl, mBitmap); // why does this not work when texturing the cube it disappears 

    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);

    gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    cubeBuff = makeFloatBuffer(camObjCoord);
    texBuff = makeFloatBuffer(camTexCoords);        
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, cubeBuff);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuff);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}   

/**
 * Generates a texture from bitmap which is being dynamically updated
 */

void bindCameraTexture(GL10 gl,Bitmap bitmap) {

    //Makes this thread safe due to resorce sharing
    synchronized(this) {
        if (cameraTexture==null)
            cameraTexture=new int[1];
        else
            gl.glDeleteTextures(1, cameraTexture, 0);

        gl.glGenTextures(1, cameraTexture, 0);
        int tex = cameraTexture[0];
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0); 

        //bitmap.getPixels(pixels, offset, stride, x, y, width, height)

        //gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_LUMINANCE, 256, 256, 0, GL10.GL_LUMINANCE, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ByteBuffer.wrap(glCameraFrame));
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        //Look into playing video of screen
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The dynamic texturing works with out the transparent background
- The untextured 3d cube works on the camera preview

My initial guess is that the texturing of the cube and the camera preview are affecting each other some how.

---

Code Update: I have been experimenting with different ways to texture an opengl camera overlay with out the camera preview disappearing and i stumbled on to something.

I now get a texture onto the Opengl Cube however the camera preview seems to be on the opengl cube as well

I thought it would be interesting to make this code available also.

---

Camera CLass

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CameraSurfaceView  extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

Camera mCamera;
boolean isPreviewRunning = false;
Camera.PreviewCallback callback;

CameraSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    //this.callback=callback;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    SurfaceHolder mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}
//mPreview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100,100))

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    synchronized(this) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();

        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();  
        p.setPreviewSize(240, 160);
        mCamera.setParameters(p);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Camera", "mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);");
        }

        mCamera.startPreview();
        //mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    synchronized(this) {
        try {
            if (mCamera!=null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();  
                isPreviewRunning=false;
                mCamera.release();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Camera", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

}

public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
    if (callback!=null)
        callback.onPreviewFrame(arg0, arg1);        
}

}
```

---

Square SquareRenderer Class

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;

import android.content.*;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import java.lang.Math;


class SquareRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer 
{
    public SquareRenderer(boolean useTranslucentBackground,Context context) 
    {
        mTranslucentBackground = useTranslucentBackground;
        this.context=context;
        mSquare = new Square();
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
    {

        gl.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //int resid = test.com.google.R.drawable.ic_launcher;   
        //mSquare.createTexture(gl, this.context, resid);           //2
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,(float)Math.sin(mTransY), -3.0f);

        mSquare.draw(gl);

        mTransY += .075f;
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) 
    {
         gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

         /*
          * Set our projection matrix. This doesn't have to be done
          * each time we draw, but usually a new projection needs to
          * be set when the viewport is resized.
          */

         float ratio = (float) width / height;
         gl.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
         gl.glLoadIdentity();
         gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);

         //int resid = book.BouncySquare.R.drawable.hedly;
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) 
    {
        /*
         * By default, OpenGL enables features that improve quality
         * but reduce performance. One might want to tweak that
         * especially on software renderer.
         */

        //glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);

        gl.glDisable(GL11.GL_DITHER);

        /*
         * Some one-time OpenGL initialization can be made here
         * probably based on features of this particular context
         */

         int resid = test.com.google.R.drawable.ic_launcher;    
         mSquare.createTexture(gl, this.context, resid);            //2

         gl.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,
                 GL11.GL_FASTEST);

         if (mTranslucentBackground) {
             gl.glClearColor(.5f,.5f,.5f,1.0f);
         } else {
             gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
         }
         gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
         gl.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
         gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }
    private boolean mTranslucentBackground;
    private Square mSquare;
    private float mTransY;
    private float mAngle;
    private Context context;
}
```

---

Square Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.opengl.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;

/**
 * A vertex shaded square.
 */
class Square
{
    public Square()
    {
        float vertices[] = 
        {
                -1.0f, -1.0f,
                 1.0f, -1.0f,
                -1.0f,  1.0f,
                 1.0f,  1.0f
        }; 

        byte maxColor=(byte)255;

        byte colors[] = 
        {
                maxColor,maxColor,       0,maxColor,
                0,       maxColor,maxColor,maxColor,
                0,              0,       0,maxColor,
                maxColor,       0,maxColor,maxColor
        }; 

        byte indices[] = 
        {
            0, 3, 1,
            0, 2, 3
        };

        float[] textureCoords =     
        {                       
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f      
        };

        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mFVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        mFVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        mFVertexBuffer.position(0);

        mColorBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length);
        mColorBuffer.put(colors);
        mColorBuffer.position(0);

        mIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
        mIndexBuffer.put(indices);
        mIndexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoords.length * 4);
        tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mTextureBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
        mTextureBuffer.put(textureCoords);
        mTextureBuffer.position(0); 
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl)
    { 
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, mColorBuffer);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);                //1
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);                 //2 

        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_SRC_COLOR);         //3
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);      //4 

        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, mTextureBuffer);   //5
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);        //6 

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);          //7

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);       //8
    }

    private int[] textures = new int[1];

    public int createTexture(GL10 gl, Context contextRegf, int resource) 
    {

        Bitmap tempImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(contextRegf.getResources(), resource); // 1

        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0); // 2
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]); // 3

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, tempImage, 0); // 4

        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR); // 5a
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR); // 5b   

        tempImage.recycle();//6

        return resource;

    }

    private Float mTransY;
    public FloatBuffer  mTextureBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer mFVertexBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer  mColorBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer  mIndexBuffer;
}
```

---

Main Activity Class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class CameraAndOpengGLActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private CameraSurfaceView mPreview;
    private GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our
        // Activity
        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        mPreview = new CameraSurfaceView(this);
        // We want an 8888 pixel format because that's required for
        // a translucent window.
        // And we want a depth buffer.
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        // Tell the cube renderer that we want to render a translucent version
        // of the cube:
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new SquareRenderer(true,this.getApplicationContext()));
        // Use a surface format with an Alpha channel:
        mGLSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        //setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
        frame.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
        frame.addView(mPreview);
        setContentView(frame);
        //addContentView(mPreview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  

        //setContentView(frame);
    }
        //FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);

        //mPreview = new CameraSurfaceView(this);

        //frame.addView(mPreview);

        //setContentView(frame);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our
        // Activity
        //mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        // We want an 8888 pixel format because that's required for
        // a translucent window.
        // And we want a depth buffer.
        //mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        // Tell the cube renderer that we want to render a translucent version
        // of the cube:
        //mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new CubeRenderer(true));
        // Use a surface format with an Alpha channel:
        //mGLSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        //setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);

 }
```

Comment: Im happy to provide source code

Comment: I have just discovered commenting out "this.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);" stops the cube from disappearing too however the background is no longer transparent.

Comment: Looking into creating a smaller application which just renders a single texture rather then dynamic and placing that onto the screen

Comment: Put glGetError in your loop if you are not currently, it will tell you if there are latent OpenGL problems that you can fix. Also where is *createTexture* source? Seems like that would be important.

Comment: Ignore create texture it was an attempt at removing a few variables that could have been affecting the transparent backround will give glGetError a go.

Comment: Its strange it renders the 3d cube on the screen with a transparent back round when i don't apply a texture but as soon as i add a texture it disappears and all you get is the camera preview.

Comment: gl.glGetError() Didn't come up with anything

Comment: Okay a quick update i completely re-did the code and I still get the same problem as soon as i add a texture the Application no longer displays the cube and only the camera preview

Comment: I think this is an android issue or maybe a thread issue not sure

Comment: Update: I forgot to mention the Android device is a HTC XE running 4.0

Comment: mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new SquareRenderer(true,this.getApplicationContext())); Is the interesting bit

Comment: I have a solution but its rubbish comment if you want to know what it is who knows maybe it'll help you instead of me

Comment: So have you found a solution? This question isn't solved yet. Or if really not yet, try to specify your question, please. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if its too late for you but I thinkg the problem is probably simple:

```
setContentView(glView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
addContentView(camera, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

You are adding the camera image on top of the glView. So perhaps you can try to turn it the other way around? Ah, anyway you certainly found a solution already. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and if only it was that simple i tried so many ways i did in-fact switch them round however the problem did persist i solved it by using trial and error in the end. Your welcome to try if you don't believe me. : ) don't worry i got a good mark